# MobaXterm local terminal error: "could not open input file"

Tags: windows, bash, shell, command-line, command-line-interface

E.g. `could not open input file`:

[image]

But it works outside mobaxterm on other terminals

Git Bash:

[image]

cmd:

[image]

I have Windows PATH setting toggled in settings. Terminal works fine connecting to remote servers.

Windows 10 x64

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the PATH.

Try this in MobaX

```
php -f "C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar"
```

You'll see it works.

You need either

- Place composer.bat in directory registered with WIN environment
  variable (Path) and create alias command for MobaX.
- Create a wrapping bash script to convert MobaX paths to WIN paths.

MobaX is build on Cygwin and Cygwin has same problems based on WIN paths which is easily fixable with bash wrapper script to have a global solution for all command (2) or you can go option (1) for composer only.